# Can I restart Bluetooth from the terminal?

Tags: bluetooth, terminal

I have a rooted Galaxy S 2 (I9100) and was wondering if I can restart the Bluetooth on my phone via the terminal client on my phone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following terminal command should enable Bluetooth via adb shell or Terminal Emulator app:

```
su
am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
```

On most versions of Android, this command will present a pop-up window to the user asking to confirm request to enable BT.  I believe this was done for security purposes whenever an app that is not system is toggling BT.

I haven't found a way to disable BT via a shell command unfortunately.

With WiFi it's a lot easier, and does not prompt user for permission:

```
su
svc wifi enable
```

will turn it on, and

```
su
svc wifi disable
```

will turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try the same. Could you also list the same for WiFi?

Comment: Edited my answer with the WiFi info.  I haven't found a way to disable BT via a terminal command though :(

Answer (score 6):

in android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager, there some parameters

> TRANSACTION_registerAdapter = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
>   TRANSACTION_unregisterAdapter = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 1);
>   TRANSACTION_registerStateChangeCallback = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 2);
>   TRANSACTION_unregisterStateChangeCallback = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 3);
>   TRANSACTION_isEnabled = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 4);
>   TRANSACTION_enable = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 5);
>   TRANSACTION_enableNoAutoConnect = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 6);
>   TRANSACTION_disable = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 7);
>   TRANSACTION_getAddress = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 8);
>   TRANSACTION_getName = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 9);

android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION=1

SO, with rooted device,
if you want to turn off bluetooth
in adb shell super user mode (su)

```
service call bluetooth_manager 8
```

if you want to turn on bluetooth again

```
service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

Comment: device I use is HTC One with android 4.4.2

Comment: Confirm, that this is working on Android 4.2.2

Comment: `Service bluetooth_manager does not exist` on Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 3):

Enable bluetooth:
`service call bluetooth 3`

Disable bluetooth:
`service call bluetooth 4`

Comment: Negative voter: could you help identifying the issue with this answer (after edit)? These worked in my rooted phone after `su` - so technically nothing wrong AFAIK.

Comment: Enable bluetooth:
service call bluetooth 3

Disable bluetooth:
service call bluetooth 5 is working on my HTC Desire X

Comment: `service call bluetooth 5` works in my Android 4.2.1 to disable bluetooth.

Comment: On a "Galaxy Fame GT-6810P", the correct numbers are 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

This works from a shell:

`am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE &
input keyevent 20 & adb shell input keyevent 21 & adb shell input keyevent 23`

Basically it causes the dialogue to appear and then sends keystrokes to accept the command

Answer (score 0):

My solution works.

```
am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
sleep 1
input tap 872 1072
```

Notice that when execute first command, it jumps out a window ask you to select ALLOW.

So you need the auto click command.

You can get the X,Y position by enable Developer options->Pointer location, then touch the ALLOW button.