# Toogle 3G, Bluetooth, and WiFi with Android Linux or ADB commands

Tags: adb, shell, terminal, command-line

Since I have not found an Android command reference list (with meaning and usage of the command), I have some questions:

- Can I disable/enable 3G?
- Can I disable/enable bluetooth?
- Can I switch from one WiFi access point to anotother WiFi access point?

If yes, how?

Comment: @MattLin I donot understand your question ? Sorry for late replay.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21320/96277