# Can WiFi and Bluetooth be enabled through adb using Fire TV Sticks USB connection?

Tags: adb, wi-fi, bluetooth, amazon-fire-tv-stick

Think I've bricked my first-gen Amazon Fire TV Stick. It's had a good run though, installed a bunch of different apps and one was a task optimizer.

It has disabled the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth on the device and now it can't be remotely controlled at all. I have the stick plugged into the laptop through USB and connected to adb but no idea if I can control it through that or input a code to enable either the WiFi or Bluetooth.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, try this: [Can I restart Bluetooth from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21373/209414)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Dan. Unfortunately none of that worked  does the fact my firetick is unrooted make a difference? Is that code only for rooted device?

Comment: Oh yes, you need rooted device hence the 'su' prior to command

Comment: Ah ok thank you, is there anything that can be done with an unrooted device to turn WiFi or Bluetooth back on? Apologies for my persistence pretty frustrated with it.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable way is doing it via input key events as suggested here: [How to turn off Wifi via ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/how-to-turn-off-wifi-via-adb)

*But in this case we need to turn it on using a similar proceedure*

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23
```

> The first line launch "wifi.WifiSettings" activity which open the WiFi Settings page. The second line simulate key presses.

These keys may not be the exact for your device in which case use appropriate [key events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) and play around until you hit the best match :)

Also for bluetooth try this:

Using adb enter;

`am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE & input keyevent 20 & adb shell input keyevent 21 & adb shell input keyevent 23`

Source: [Can I restart Bluetooth from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21373/209414)

Answer (score 0):

Use your TV remote to control it. As long as your TV supports HDMI CEC, you can control the FireStick with the TV. Just make sure HDMI CEC is enabled in TV settings as well as in FireStick settings.

If that doesn't work, try a powered USB OTG cable and plug in a USB controller that has XInput, or plug in a PlayStation controller or Xbox One controller via a micro USB cable.